# Attach a file from local storage using Jest+Supertest

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, jestjs, supertest

I want to upload a file to endpoint with PUT request using Jest + Supertest.

I have following request constructor:

```
export async function uploadFileForJob(
  uploadUrl: string,
  accessToken: string,
  filePath: string
) {
  const upload_file_for_job = await request(uploadUrl)
    .put("")
    .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
    .set("Content-Type", "model/gltf-binary")
    .attach('file', filePath)
  return upload_file_for_job;
}
```

and the request in test file itself:

```
const UploadFileForJob = await uploadFileForJob(
      uploadUrl,
      accessToken,
      'C:/Job/Simulations/TestTshirt_04.glb'
    );
    expect(UploadFileForJob.status).toEqual(200);
```

The endpoint always returns 200 to me and has no body in response, so I have another way of checking if file was actually correctly uploaded:

```
export async function getJobView(jobId: string, accessToken: string) {
  const get_job_view = await request(`https://${config.url}`)
    .get(`/products-v0/_objects/${jobId}/Views/File`)
    .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
    .send();
  return get_job_view;
}
```

```
    const GetJobView = await getJobView(jobId, accessToken);
    expect(GetJobView.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(GetJobView.body.view).toBeTruthy();
```

and here I already get 404 error which indicates that file wasn't correctly accepted by previous endpoint. I am sure that the error lies in a way how jest takes the route which I point to it and there are no errors in any variables, if I use all the same with Postman (using binary body file selector) everything works perfectly. What should be the way of writing this .attach in a correct way?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solution is found. There were two problems.
First was that uploading of a file takes some time, so next request should be sent after uploading of the file is finished, for it I used do...while loop with some retries checking that file is finally attached.

```
    // Wait for the file to be attached to the job
let JobViewResponse;
const maxRetries = 20; // Number of retries before giving up
let retries = 0;

do {
  // Introduce a small delay between each retry (e.g., 2 seconds)
  await sleep(2000);

  JobViewResponse = await getJobView(jobId, accessToken);
  retries++;
} while (JobViewResponse.status !== 200 && retries < maxRetries);

// Check if the file is attached to the job
if (JobViewResponse.status === 200 && JobViewResponse.body.view) {
  const viewData = JSON.parse(JobViewResponse.body.view);
  expect(JobViewResponse.status).toEqual(200);
  expect(JobViewResponse.body.view).toBeTruthy();
  expect(viewData.Size).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  console.log("File is attached to the job.");
} else {
  console.error("File attachment to the job failed or took too long.");
}
```

Second problem was that attach() tries to send the file as multipart form data. But in our case, the request body should only contain the raw bytes. To solve it, I used fs.readFileSync to read the file in memory first.

```
    export async function uploadFileForJob(
  uploadUrl: string,
  accessToken: string,
  filePath: string
) {
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const upload_file_for_job = await request(uploadUrl)
    .put("")
    .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
    .set("Content-Type", "model/gltf-binary")
    .send(fileContents);
  return upload_file_for_job;
}
```